# Loop Through PHP Array Encoded In JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a PHP array that has a table id as the key and a table field as the value.

Example PHP:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $array[$id] = $row['some_field'];
}
```

I then use `json_encode($array)` to get something like:

```
{"id1":"value1","abc":"123","xyz":"789"}
```

How can I loop through this in jQuery? From what I have found so far it seems like I need to know the key. So:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonVar);
alert(obj.abc); //prints 123
```

But how can I get these values if I don't know the keys since they are dynamic?

Do I need to restructure my PHP array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you encode an associative array in php into a JSON object it is no longer an array, it is an object with keys and values. You can iterate through them in javascript using [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
for (var key in obj) {
   console.log(obj[key]);
}
```

**Note:** `for..in` does not garuntee order, if you need to ensure order you will have to make your array indexed, instead of `key=>value`, and use a `for` loop (or `while`) instead.

Comment: Got it. I was under the assumption that I could not use `for..in` because of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-a-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript). Then I reread the part that says "for..in is for enumerating an **object's** properties", thinking I had an array. So, exactly what I needed after all. Thank you.

Comment: Note that even though it's not considered best practice because of the ambiguity and unguaranteed sort order you can use `for..in` to loop regular arrays as well... you just *shouldn't*.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the keys of your array using `Object.keys`, then loop through them. Unlike `for...in`, this gives you the option to [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the keys before processing them:

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj).sort();  // sorting is optional
for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
    var key = keys[i],
        val = obj[key];
    console.log(key+":"+val);
};
```

In older browsers, you'll need a polyfill to enable the `Object.keys` method. [MDN has one on their documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Comment: I got JaredMcAteer's working, but I will check this out as well. Sorting would be nice.