# appending images from php to document with javascript/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
    <?php
$imgDir =   'images/';
$images =   glob($imgDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}',GLOB_BRACE);
echo json_encode($images);  
?>

<script>
jQuery(function(){
    var phpvar  =   '<?php echo json_encode($images) ?>';
        jQuery('body').append('<img src="' + phpvar + '"/>');
    });
</script>
```

The top php scans the folder 'images' and echoes all the file pathnames. However i want to use the array formed from this and append it to the document/body to display the images using . But i'm not sure how to pass the php variable '$images' to jquery/javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202712/loop-through-php-array-encoded-in-json

Comment: Are you want to access php variable in jquery ?

Comment: The question Why comes to mind. Unless you ajax the php created JSON, why not just use the php to write the image tags?

Comment: @mplungjan i did this:  echo '<img src="/uploads/'.json_encode($images).'"/>'; and it fails to find the images. When i right click the blank image and try to save it, it gives me "[.htm"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `phpvar` that you're creating is actually an array (provided you remove the quotes), so you need to loop through this array and add each image separately, like this:

```js
jQuery(function(){
    var phpvar = <?php echo json_encode($images) ?>;
    $.each(phpvar, function(id, image){
        jQuery('body').append('<img src="' + image + '"/>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you are wasting processing and a needless framework for simple PHP array processing.

No need for either JSON, JSONEncode or jQuery:

```
foreach (glob('images/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}',GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
  echo '<img src=".$filename.'" alt="" />'."\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$imgDir =   'images/';
$images =   glob($imgDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}',GLOB_BRACE);
$image_var ="";
foreach($images as $img)
{
$image_var.="<img src=".$img.">";
}

echo json_encode($image_var);
?>

<script>
jQuery(function(){
var phpvar  =   <?php echo json_encode($image_var) ?>;
    jQuery('body').append(phpvar);
});
</script>
```

Comment: No need whatsoever to encode that string nor to put it in quotes in the script nor to use jQuery